# How to find remains dates from two months date?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database Sample with value

```
Leave    FromDate     ToDate      EmpCode
 6       2015-01-28   2015-02-02    ABC
```

I want count of Leave =4 in january 2015 and leave count=2 in february 2015
Anybody help me...

```
eg: You applied 4 days leave 2015-01-30 to 2015-02-02. And the end of the
month your company decide to check your January month leave. They just 
entered month=1 and year=2015. Then how to get count of January month leaves from these data???
```

or

```
If have a date "2015-01-25", then how can I display the remains dates ie, 
2015-01-26,2015-01-27,2015-01-28, 2015-01-29,2015-01-30,2015-01-31 etc.
```

Comment: You should have tried with your logic. and then you could post your code that would be giving you any problem. Also, your question is a kind of paradox because, you haven't mentioned how to decided which month having how many leaves ?

Comment: @MohanLal which database ? `sqlserver` or `mysql` at backend

Answer (score 0):

You need to design a logic. Your scenario is not limited to a month gap but could be expanded for several months too . ex- 2015-01-28 to 2015-03-01 [Possible]

If you are planning to implement at front end, use methods like `DaysInMonth Method`([DOC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))  and use relevant `properties` ([DOC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day(v=vs.110).aspx)) to extract required parameters too. Also your logic need to take care about weekends and holidays if applicable

Example - If you want to calculate days for January leave for 2015-01-28

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2015-01-28", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int daysInJan = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month);
Console.WriteLine("Leave for Jan = {0}", (daysInJan - dt.Day)+1); // +1 to include starting date

// Here general holidays are not considered
```

Comment: ,My question may happen mostly in companies. Then how they are doing this. If I add any extra field can I solve it??

Comment: See the code example. You can do such calculation in front end before data is sent to database. Here i haven't considered about general holidays. In true industry there are tables with holidays of the month so they can be deducted from the calculation